# DateDiff Function Error

Tags: coldfusion

See text below:

```
    <cfoutput query="getvisit">
    <cfif DateDiff("n", TimeFormat(visit_time, "hh:mm"), TimeFormat(Now(), "hh:mm")) GTE 0>
        <cfif visit_logo NEQ "">
            <img src="images/highschools/#visit_logo#.jpg" width="175" height="149" class="logo" />
        </cfif>
            #visit_name# from <br />#visit_#high_school#
    </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
```

When I run this I get the following error message:

Context validation error for the cfif tag. The start tag must have a matching end tag. An explicit end tag can be provided by adding </cfif>. If the body of the tag is empty, you can use the shortcut <cfif .../>.

The CFML compiler was processing:

- The body of a cfoutput tag beginning on line 32, column 10.

The error occurred on line -1.

Can anyone point to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `#visit_#high_school#` is the error. You are missing a pound here.

Comment: @Beginner is right. But over that you're passing strings to a function expecting dates. `timeFormat()` should only ever be used for output, not data processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many # in your code.

This line:

```
 #visit_name# from <br />#visit_#high_school#
```

Should most likely be:

```
 #visit_name# from <br />#visit_high_school#
```